# Cast Numeric to Float in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, casting

I have a generic function like the following:

```
def foo[N: Numeric](bar: N) = bar.asInstanceOf[Float]
```

When I call it with an Int type like so:

```
foo(1) //Fails, if it was a Float it would work fine though.
```

It fails at runtime. Why can't I cast like this and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I cast like this

<s>Because `N` is of type `Int` and not of type `Float`. An explicit cast will still not make these types align, you need to *convert* one type to another.</s>

As @jwvh points out, it is possible to cast an `Int` to a `Float` and vise versa:

```
scala> (1.0).asInstanceOf[Int]
res14: Int = 1

scala> (1).asInstanceOf[Float]
res15: Float = 1.0
```

But a conversion from `java.lang.Integer` to `scala.Float` will fail:

```
scala> Integer.valueOf(1).asInstanceOf[Float]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToFloat(BoxesRunTime.java:109)
  ... 29 elided
```

Due to boxing/unboxing (Still, using the properties of `Numeric` for this task will be safer).

> how do I make it work?

`Numeric` has a bunch of `toX` methods. You're looking for `toFloat`:

```
def foo[N: Numeric](bar: N) = implicitly[Numeric[N]].toFloat(bar)
```

Yields

```
scala> foo(1)
res10: Float = 1.0
```

Note `implicitly` is used here to summon the implicit `Numeric[N]` evidence you required with the context bound on `N`.

Comment: An `Int` _can_ be cast to `Float`, but a `java.lang.Integer` cannot, and, for some reason, that's what `N` is before the attempted cast.

Comment: @jwvh Interesting, I thought that cast would fail. I'll correct my answer.